# WFS vector layer not rendering with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I'm having problems trying to load a Geoserver/WFS vector layer using OpenLayers. I can see GML data loading in Firebug and also I can see the layer name is in the layer switcher but the the data is not rendering. I've added my code below. I've seen similar questions on here that have helped me a lot with this so far but I can't see anything else to make it work.

Can anyone see anything I've missed or done wrong?

```
    wfs1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("CamEO Boundary", {
        strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version : "1.0.0",
        url : "http://domain.co.uk/geoserver/wfs", 
        featurePrefix : "riversdata",
        featureType : "cameo",
        featureNS : "http://domain.co.uk/riversdata",
        srsName: "EPSG:27700",
        geometryName : "geom"
        }),
        format : new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
        'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700"),
        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
      }),
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        strokeWidth: 3,
        strokeColor: "#333333" })

      });

map.addLayer(wfs1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this after some sleep and coffee. Changes below:

- Changed the strategy to BBOX - I don't think this was preventing the
  map rendering but I think this setting is preferable as it prevents
  the whole data set loading.
- Changed the version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0    (version 1.0.0 does not
  automatically reproject different SRS)
- Changed srsName to the same as the base map.

Here's the new code:

```
 wfs1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        "CamEO Boundary", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version : "1.1.0",
        url : "http://centralgeo.co.uk/geoserver/wfs", 
        featurePrefix : "riversdata",
        featureType : "cameo",
        featureNS : "http://centralgeo.co.uk/riversdata",
        srsName: "EPSG:900913", //must be same as base map
        geometryName : "geom"
        }),
```